Flutter issue web
we use the same flutter project for the mobile and pc, and when we use for the mobile its work fine all thing but when we use the web we get that two error,
Warning: In index.html:46: "FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint" is deprecated. Use "FlutterLoader.load" instead.
[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Load asset from assets/translations
Error while trying to load an asset: Flutter Web engine failed to fetch "assets/assets/translations/en-.json". HTTP request succeeded, but the server responded with HTTP status 404.

If your project created by older flutter versions, you need to upgrade your index.html file, check this out: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/initialization#upgrading-an-older-project

Try these steps to update your /web directory for the latest initialization.

Remove the files from your /web directory.

From your project directory, run the following:
flutter create . --platforms=web



